# Query throws an error new declare string on create function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to create a function in SQL Server and I get this error:

> [S0001][102] Incorrect syntax near '@string2'

at line

```
DECLARE @string2 VARCHAR(255) = @s;
```

I created many functions but never get this kind of error

Here is complete

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetMeterNumber(@s AS VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX) AS
BEGIN
    IF @s IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @string2 VARCHAR(255) = @s;
        @string2 = REPLACE(REPLACE(LEFT(REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(@string2), CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(@string2)) - 1)),
                                      CHARINDEX('-',
                                                REVERSE(
                                                    LEFT(REVERSE(@string2), CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(@string2)) - 1)))
                                      - 1), 'NUMBER_', ''), '_OF_10', '')
        RETURN @string2
    END
END
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

You're starting a statement with `@string2 = ...` when I assume you meant to put a `set` or `select` there

Comment: I changed  query to this but still same error `SELECT  REPLACE(REPLACE(LEFT(REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(@string2), CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(@string2)) - 1)),
                                      CHARINDEX('-',
                                                REVERSE(
                                                    LEFT(REVERSE(@string2), CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(@string2)) - 1)))
                                      - 1), 'NUMBER_', ''), '_OF_10', '') INTO @string2`

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your variable (`@s`), it should be declared before `BEGIN` & return should go after `END` :

So, the correct version would be :

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetMeterNumber(@s AS VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX) AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @string2 VARCHAR(MAX) = @s

  IF @s IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN

      SET @string2 = REPLACE(REPLACE(LEFT(REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(@string2), CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(@string2)) - 1)),
                                      CHARINDEX('-',
                                                REVERSE(
                                                    LEFT(REVERSE(@string2), CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(@string2)) - 1)))
                                      - 1), 'NUMBER_', ''), '_OF_10', '')

    END

  RETURN @string2
END
```

EDIT :  I would add some prevention at the core loigc :

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(LEFT(REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(@string2), CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(@string2 + '/')) - 1)),
                                      CHARINDEX('-',
                                                REVERSE(
                                                    LEFT(REVERSE(@string2), CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(@string2 + '/')) - 1) + '-'))
                                      - 1), 'NUMBER_', ''), '_OF_10', '')
```

Comment: I'm not sure what a valid input value looks like, but I get errors in the logic part of the function "Msg 537, Level 16, State 3, Line 21
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function." Not that you need to address this, but more for the OP.

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean. . .  That is the core logic issue, so you need to understand the function core logic (`replace() . . . .`) & pass the correct parameter inside function or just ask to OP for the logic.

Comment: The function has been created but it give error 537

Comment: @YogeshSharma Like, I said, that is more for the OP to worry about. Your answer solves the problem the OP had, so +1. But the OP needs to review/correct their logic.

Comment: @TalhaAfzal Sounds like you have a new question to post :)

Comment: For me it a problem I am trying to solve from last one hour

Comment: @TalhaAfzal. . . Just ensure that the `@string2` has same length variable declared as `@s`.

Comment: this it the string that the function will get 
`abc.org.c/items/item_database/number_3_of_10-klsnfdsfjsd.txt`

Comment: @TalhaAfzal. . .  I have added some prevention & use that edited part  in your function.

Comment: @YogeshSharma I applied changes the error is gone but it gives me empty columns

Comment: The Replace.... query works fine with select that I posted in question I am just trying to make a function of it....